# Multiple jquery statements in if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to submit a form only if the text fields are properly filled out. I get an error saying its expecting the end of if statement but its the start of another jquery statement. How do i string multiple statements in an if statement?

```
<input type="image" id="signinsubmit" src="images/signinBtn.jpg"> </br> <p id='signupbutton'>
<a href='subscription.php'>Sign Up </a> </p>
 <script type="text/javascript">

function validateForm() {

  // verify input
  var phone = $("#signupphoneNumber").val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

  if( $("#signupUsername").val().length < 4 || $("#signupPassword").val().length < 8 || $("#signupownerName").val().length < 1 $("#signupEmail").val().indexOf("@") < 0 || $("#signupEmail").val().indexOf(".com") < 0 || phone.length < 10  )
  {
return false;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the operator (presumably `||`) after this bit:

```
$("#signupownerName").val().length < 1
```

This would be more obvious if you included some line breaks:

```
if( $("#signupUsername").val().length < 4 ||
    $("#signupPassword").val().length < 8 ||
    $("#signupownerName").val().length < 1                 // <-- here's the problem
    $("#signupEmail").val().indexOf("@") < 0 ||
    $("#signupEmail").val().indexOf(".com") < 0 ||
    phone.length < 10  ) {
  return false;
}
```

(As an aside, note that email addresses do *not* have to have `.com` in them - what about `.net` or `.gov` or any of the new top-level domains that have been sprouting lately?)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#signupownerName").val().length < 1 $("#signupEmail").val().indexOf("@") < 0
```

Missing `||` here. Pay closer attention next time, please ;)

Also, you'd be far better off ditching that and just doing:

```
<input type="text" name="name" required />
<input type="email" name="email" required />
<input type="text" name="phone" pattern="[0-9]+" />
```

And so on. HTML5 is here, use it!

Comment: isn't html 5 not recognized on every browser yet?

Comment: @Kolink - So you don't know anybody whose work environment is still stuck in IE7-9? (As far as I know form validation attributes weren't supported until IE10, were they?)

Comment: @nnnnnn I know people who use Lynx. Not even jQuery can help you there.